# How to handle relations in jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2 with spring data

In a one to many relation, when we want to remove relation in a rest architecture what should be the good way to do it

Child and Parent continue to exist... only relation must be removed

```
@DeleteMapping(value="/{id}/child/{childId}")
public void deleteChildRelation(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @PathVariable("childId") Integer childId){
    service.deleteChildRelation(id, childId);
}
```

We can get parent, remove child and save

Or use query annotation and do something like

```
@Query("update Child c set c.parent=null where c.id=:id ")
void deleteChildRelation(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: What is your doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is the JPA way to do it. It is slower but leaves you with a consistent session employs optimistic locking and it also updates JPAs 2nd level cache. You should use it if this is of use for you.

If you just want the relation to be gone, the second approach is faster and simpler, since it does a single database round trip.